# My university uses SMBv1 for file shares. Is manually enabling SMBv1 on my Windows 10 machine a bad idea?

Tags: networking, security, smb

My university has network drives set up using the SMBv1 protocol. They instruct students to manually enable SMBv1 in Windows before trying to access these, since SMBv1 is currently disabled. There are important files kept on one of these shares that I need to access on a regular basis.

I am aware of the EternalBlue exploit for SMBv1, and WannCry, etc.

Are there potential direct consequences of enabling SMBv1? If I enable SMBv1, is Windows 10 still properly patched for remote code execution via EternalBlue? My machine is connected to a network with 1000s of other machines, which is primarily why I'm concerned here.

I briefly attempted to ask my department's IT supervisor, but he mostly laughed at me for being worried about this at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there potential direct consequences of enabling SMBv1?

Microsoft does not consider SMBv1 to be safe, which is one of the reasons, it is now disabled by default on Windows 10 version 1703+. **All versions of Windows 10 released after March 14, 2017, are protected against all known EternalBlue exploits.**

> is Windows 10 still properly patched for remote code execution via EternalBlue?

[Windows 10 version 1507](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4012606/windows-10-update-kb4012606), [Windows 10 version 1511](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4013198/windows-10-update-kb4013198), and [Windows 10 version 1607](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4013429/windows-10-update-kb4013429) all received security updates for all known vulerabilities connected to EternalBlue ([Microsoft Security Bulletin MS17-010](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/SecurityBulletins/2017/ms17-010#vulnerability-information)).

- [CVE-2017-0143](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-0143)
- [CVE-2017-0144](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-0144)
- [CVE-2017-0145](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-0145)
- [CVE-2017-0146](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-0146)
- [CVE-2017-0147](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-0147)
- [CVE-2017-0148](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-0148)

> My machine is connected to a network with 1000s of other machines, which is primarily why I'm concerned here.

You are absolutely warranted to have this concern.  However, if your system is patched, you have taken all known steps to prevent your machine from being vulnerable. Since not having access to these share drives is likely not an option.  **You will have to make the decision if the potential for unknown SMBv1 exploits is worth keeping it enabled.**

> I briefly attempted to ask my department's IT supervisor, but he mostly laughed at me for being worried about this at all.

The supervisor certainly shouldn't have laughed at you, when their department is using a known vulnerable version of SMB, but there are indeed legitimate reasons for to continue SMBv1 support.